# ionic 2 local notification not showing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working with ionic 2 local notification for the first time. I've  followed this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJfRgswp3w8).

When I test my app in Xcode, I'm getting a warning message below and the notification message doesn't show... not sure why.

> WARN: Unknown property: at

I have installed

> ionic cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification
>
> npm install --save @ionic-native/local-notifications

and added the plugin as a provider in **src/app/app.module.ts**

I have following code:

**home.html:**

```
<button ion-button (click)=myNotifications()>Test</button>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform, ActionSheetController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
    
        
    export class HomePage {
    
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                  public platform: Platform,
                  private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation,
                  private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
                  public alertCtrl: AlertController ) {
    
                    this.platform.ready().then((ready) =>{
                      this.localNotifications.on('click', (notification, state) => {
                        let json = JSON.parse(notification.data);
    
                        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                          title: notification.title,
                          message: json.fullMsq
                        });
                        alert.present();
                      });
                    });
      }
    
      myNotifications() {
    
        this.localNotifications.schedule({
          id: 1,
          title: 'ABC Meeting Notification',
          text: 'ABC Meeting will start in 20 mins',
          at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 20*60*1000),
          data: { fullMsq: 'this is the full notification message' }
        })
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer Notification Demo:
https://github.com/husainsr/Ionic3_Notification
May it Proves Helpful to you.

Comment: Followed the instructions and installed the app on android device and xcode simulator, the date picker does not show up or the device keyboard. Hence can't test the notifications.

Comment: can u please inspect it and give me more info if there exists any error or not?

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available

Comment: As mention in error cordova is not available try installing cordova and try again.

Comment: u need real device in order to check the cordova plugin

Comment: I have reinstalled cordova and I'm testing on a real device i.e. Google Pixel. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: using -->ionic cordova run android

Comment: Yes, ionic cordova run android and have tried ionic cordova build android, which builds successfully and I can install the .apk file on a real device.

Comment: Basically I downloaded and created a new app using the your Github project. This app builds fine and I have it installed on a real device but the date picker doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to kindly update the github repository with ion-datetime so I can see a working example, please. Thank you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OzrMjCjpnkJXpl-dSOZ7fgs4V_JTGGn9    Here i had modified src file just download remove u r existing src file and paste this instead. Hope it works.

Comment: Excellent it now works :) Can I ask what you changed, I can't seem to spot any code changes. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162422/discussion-between-husain-and-greendome).

Comment: upvote and accept the answer , i had used ion-datetime instead native datepicker refer the code for more info.

Comment: I've accepted the answer, sorry for the delay. I thought I did it at the same time as the up-vote. I've moved this discussion to chat for further assistance:) Thanks,