# Ionic 3 local notification in background app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

How to create local notification in background app for Ionic 3? I have try tutorial in here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/ but it just for foreground app

Thank's in advance..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046125/ionic-2-local-notification-not-showing/48048630#48048630

Comment: Thank's for your help :) @Husain

Comment: Welcome dear, try to upvote that answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should schedule your notification in a specific time.
for example this notification will be triggered after an hour.

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
   text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
   at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600),//add 3600 seconds to current time.

});
```

Comment: If I want to send this notification every day at 10 am then what should I need to do?

Comment: This did not answer the question

Comment: If You have advanced customisation for background task It is better to use native platform. Until now (ionic 6) ionic platform doesn't support advanced customisation for any of background tasks.